# file.createNewFile() not working immediately

Tags: java, eclipse

```
File file = null;
String directory = "/Users/Chris/Documents/Sites/gmustudent/WebContent/images/test/";
file = new File(directory + imageName);
file.createNewFile();
```

The code above does effectively create a new file in the directory I want with the name I want. And after I run it I can go to that path on my computer and the images will be there. But the images will not be visible in eclipse. After I run this code the directory looks like this

[image]

So I can view the images in the directory in my computer but eclipse does not see them yet. So then I right click my project and click refresh...

[image]

And then my directory is refreshed...

[image]

So when I try to access the images I just uploaded in my web app I can't see them until I refresh my entire web app.

**UPDATE**

This is an issue b/c I need to access these files through their path online. like htttp://localhost:8086/gmustudent/images/test/image.png. I can't do this until I refresh the web app which is the problem. So when I try and access the images after upload I can't see them until I refresh the eclipse project.

Comment: why do you need to see it in eclipse ?

Comment: Does that _Refresh_ button append some necessary fields to an _.xml_ or _manifest_ file? If so, you may need dynamically check for changes in your directory to get image names for appending.

Comment: @JigarJoshi because the OP is using Eclipse to run the web server.

Comment: @Matt but why do we need to see it updated in eclipse's view ? it is already created on disk

Comment: @JigarJoshi the reason has been added in an update

Comment: @JigarJoshi I'm guessing that Eclipse is deploying static files to somewhere else, like a WAR (exploded or not) in a Tomcat deploy directory.

Comment: Why do you need to create zero-length files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer versions of Eclipse, there's a Workspace preference called "Refresh using native hooks or polling."

[image]

This has potential to slow Eclipse and/or your system down if it needs to read a slow (say, non-SSD) disk and/or many directories/files. [This help doc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/platform_whatsnew.html) hints that the native hooks only work on Windows versions of Eclipse, implying that Linux & Mac versions will use polling, which will likely be less efficient.

Give it a shot; YMMV.

Comment: Thank you but this does not help the issue. I made an update maybe that might help you help me

Comment: Try picking a different directory to write to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793856/whats-a-good-place-to-save-a-file-to-in-a-java-app

Comment: WOAH ! took a sec but now it all works great! Thank you so much! When I deploy this off of my localhost and onto mochahost my hosting provider is there anyway I can set this up there too or should the file uploads be fine and immediate?

Comment: It really depends on the specifics of your deployment. Locally, in some setups, Eclipse does some magic to compile & move files into a `deploy` directory. Not knowing how you're deploying in production, I can't say exactly – but there's certainly no Eclipse workspace there. Note, you really don't want to hardcode that path because it almost certainly won't exist in production.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. How should I get the directory in this case?

Comment: It depends on your hosting provider, whether or not you want the files to live there permanently (if not, try a temp dir), etc. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1793896/139010